# PHPMyAdmin Designer doesn't show all tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have created a MYSQL Database using XAMPP and PHPMyAdmin. 
The Database has been firstly created using a MYSQL script which created and connected all tables. 
In a second time I had to create and connect the table "Pietanza_nel_ordine". I created it with another SQL Query and then I connected the Foreign Keys using the tools provided by PHPMyAdmin.
This table works correctly even with Foreign Keys, however it is never shown in the Designer tool in PHPMyAdmin.
How can i get it to be shown?

Server version is 5.6.26, protocol 10.

PHPMyAdmin version is 4.4.14

I provide you with a few screenshot about my configurations:

Designer View:
[image: Designer view:]

Tables list:
[image: Tables list:]

Table Ordine:
[image: Table Ordine]

Table Pietanza_nel_ordine:
[image: Table Pietanza_nel_ordine]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found out which was the problem:
The new table was added to my DB, but it wasn't added in designer schema. 
I found out the option "Add tables from other databases" in the Designer View left dropdown, which allowed me to add my new Table in the Designer View (even if it was in the same Database).

[image]

Comment: I just noticed first option in dropdown menù is Show/Hide tables list, if you click on it it will let you select which tables to show and which to hide. It is surely best option to use this method to solve this problem. (For some reason deafult is hidden for new tables).

Comment: Thx Agnohendrix, this is the way